# No internet connection in Android after using Mitmproxy

Tags: proxy, mitmproxy

I have configured the android Phone (Samsung Galaxy S8) to use proxy. I can connect to mitm.it. I can also see some requests captured by Mitmproxy.

However, I got no internet connection when I try to search anything in Google.

Any hints on what happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Android 7.1 and higher [do not longer allow the use of custom certificates manually added by the user](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html) but if you have a phone with super user access, you can make it work via ADB.

Android stores its system certificates in `/system/etc/security/cacerts/`. If you take a look at your device, you will see that the certificates have hashed names, eg. "a1234b0d.0". To intercept app traffic, you need to find out the hash of your certificate

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem | head -1
```

Then rename your certificate accordingly

```
mv mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem <your_hash_value_in_here_without_carets>.0
```

And finally move it to where your device's system certificates are. For this, however, you need to remount the system directory first in order to get write access

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount,rw /system"
adb push your_certificate /sdcard/your_certificate
adb shell su -c "mv /sdcard/your_certificate /system/etc/security/cacerts/your_certificate"
adb shell su -c "chmod 644 /system/etc/security/cacerts/your_certificate"
adb reboot
```

If that doesn't work, I can remember (not the source, though) reading about Android Nougat also not regarding certificates that expire in more than 2 years. The certificates created by mitmproxy should be fine. Burpsuite or Fiddler ones did not work for me though.

Comment: I just tried this on Android 10, and it didn't regard my certificate from mitmproxy that had an expiration 2.5y in the future. I was able to use HTTP Toolkit to achieve a similar goal (even though I know it's possible to create your own root cert and have mitmproxy use that instead, I didn't want to go through the trouble).

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps use [certificate pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) and so it can detect the "fake" http://mitm.it/cert/pem that you downloaded to your phone.